# Is there a way to get the path to a specific element within the JSON value?

Tags: json, jq

Given this simple example from the jq manual:

```
[    
    {
        "name":"JSON",
        "good":true        
    },
    {
        "name":"XML",
        "good":false        
    }
]
```

using this expression:

```
.[1].name
```

I get `"XML"` as output.

And the question: in xpath, for example, there are ways to do the reverse: given an element, an xpath function will return the xpath to the element within the document. Is there a way to do that with jq? That is, given `"XML"`, is there a way to get

```
.[1].name
```

as the output?

I am aware of the `getpath(PATHS)` function, but unless I'm missing something, that's not it.

Comment: `.[1].name` doesn't make sense as an output? Do you want the index of the object containing the string?

Comment: @Inian I humbly beg to differ. In this case, it's simple. But imagine the target string is in an object somewhere in the lower layers of a deeply nested json. The purpose of the exercise is, as it were, to find the question (`.[1].name`, in this case), the answer to which is `"XML"`. Sort of like a json "Jeopardy!".... If you're familiar with xpath, it would be the jq equivalent to `fn:path(some_element)`.

Comment: Is your real JSON a bit complicated than this? If so provide an abstract of that, because the one in question seems really trivial

Comment: @Inian Well, it's trivial because I wanted to simplify the question. If you want something less trivial, take this json: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53421756/9448090 ; if the answer is `"Hogan"` - what is the question?

Comment: @oguzismail No, this version has the same problems as @peak's answer. Your answer works on both `"XML"` and `"Hogan"` (and if you change `"Hogan"` to just `200` in that json and look for that number, the original answer works as well! So so far it's the leading candidate...

Comment: Can't reproduce that bug though, post a jqplay link, I'm interested.

Comment: @oguzismail See https://jqplay.org/s/6m1GKHmQ9l.

Comment: That's not that hard to fix, but the code gets even more clumsy

Comment: @oguzismail Agreed; adding the fix to an already long expression makes it awfull; as they say, it a case of the cure being worse than the disease... I'll test a few more cases , but I think I'll go with your original answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned JQ still doesn't have a built-in for that. However, if a path in `.[1]["name"]` format is also acceptable, that's pretty easy:

- get paths in array form using `path` built-in,
- enclose each path component of type string in double quotes; `tojson` can be used for that,
- join all components by `][`,
- and put the result between `.[` and `]`.

```
path(recurse | select(.=="XML")) | ".[\(map(tojson) | join("]["))]"
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/iz1og1bn9_)</sup>

Comment: Interesting; let me look in to this, but just preliminarily: the `.[1]["name"]` format is definitely acceptable since it constitutes a question the answer to which is the target answer.

Comment: I think I'm there. Can you just please edit the answer to explain what each part of the expression does? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To get the JSON representation of the path(s) of interest, you could write:

```
paths as $p
| select(getpath($p) == "XML")
| $p
```

This form is normally the most useful, but it’s easy to transform it into another form if need be, as shown in @OguzIsmail's answer (see also below).

If only the path of the first occurrence is desired, you can simply use `first(...)`, but of course there are different possible conceptions of “first”.

### Producing jq-style path expressions

As pointed out by @OguzIsmail, `tojson` can be used to produce jq-style path expressions (i.e., jq expressions that can be used to fetch a value directly, without `getpath`), e.g. by adding the following to the above pipeline :

```
".[" + (map(tojson)|join("][")) + "]"
```

Comment: "it’s easy to transform it into another form if need be" - well "easy" is a relative term :) and the need is indeed there: the transformation is exactly what's required - it has to be an expression that, when pasted into jq play yields `"XML"`, or (if you use the json in the link in the (current) last comment to the question, yields `"Hogan"`.

Comment: See update, but it’s generally best to use the array representation with `getpath/1`.

Comment: Well, it's like this: if you try your full expression on the json in the question, the output is `".[1].name"`; it requires stripping the quote marks before plugging it back in as a search expression, so close - but no there yet. In the case of the `"Hogan"` json (in the comment) the output is `.fieldset.[0].fieldset.[0].field.[1].value.plain` and obviously raises an error if used as a search expression.

Comment: I did, how is this any different than mine? Does `tojson` have any side-effects I'm not aware of?

Comment: @OguzIsmail - How different? Mine was wrong!  Please see update.